# How to call a project (exe file) as tab on tab control winforms devexpress

Tags: c#, forms, devexpress, tabcontrol

I have an exe file on another project.
Now I want to call it and dock into a tab (tab control devexpress) when I click a button.

I don't know how to do that.
Please help me.

Comment: Sorry. Help me please

Comment: Have you tried anything or searched for it on a search engine?

Comment: Yes, I have tried many times on google search

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're talking about two different things. The first thing is call exe on another project, you can use this code to accomplish that:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.FileName = "YOUR-EXE-PATH-HERE.exe";
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.Arguments = "";

try
{
    // Start the process with the info we specified.
    // Call WaitForExit and then the using statement will close.
    using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
    {
       exeProcess.WaitForExit();
    }
}
catch
{
    // Log error.
}
```

The second thing is to dock a application to tab control, you already don't need to dock and application, that is impossible, you to dock a button or something else widget to tab control, the selected widget represents your executed application, but isn't already docked to tab control, is only a representation of the background task you're running. Programmatically you can accomplish that with:

```
ImageList imageList1 = new ImageList();
imageList1.Images.Add("key1", Image.FromFile(@"C:\path\to\file.jpg"));
imageList1.Images.Add("key2", Image.FromFile(@"C:\path\to\file.ico"));

TabControl tabControl1 = new TabControl();
tabControl1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
tabControl1.ImageList = imageList1;
tabControl1.TabPages.Add("tabKey1", "TabText1", "key1");  
tabControl1.TabPages.Add("tabKey2", "TabText2", "key2");
this.Controls.Add(tabControl1);
```

So, you need a model to represent a running process invoked by your program (external exe), and using this model add tabs with icon and .exe name (for this you surely need to read some icon data from invoked .exe) to your tab control.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I want use exe file as user control, fill design into tabpage and using as call exe file independence